# read excel with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

hiii guys i'am new in python and pandas. i have some questions about this tutorial page from pandas

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index

how to get a list of loc

```
                     A         B         C
first second                               
bar   one     0.895717  0.410835 -1.413681
      two     0.805244  0.813850  1.607920
baz   one    -1.206412  0.132003  1.024180
      two     2.565646 -0.827317  0.569605
foo   one     1.431256 -0.076467  0.875906
      two     1.340309 -1.187678 -2.211372
qux   one    -1.170299  1.130127  0.974466
      two    -0.226169 -1.436737 -2.006747

In [43]: df.loc["bar"]
Out[43]: 
               A         B         C
second                              
one     0.895717  0.410835 -1.413681
two     0.805244  0.813850  1.607920
```

in that tutorial a "bar", was directly coded on that bracket

my question is how to get a list of loc like:

loc=[bar, baz, foo, qux]

some method if i call that method it print a list of loc

```
[bar, baz, foo, qux]
```

Comment: That's the dataframe's index.  You can `print(df.index.droplevel(1))` to get the first part of the multiindex.

Comment: ok... but it become index([bar, bar, baz, baz, foo, foo, qux, qux]) ... how to be index([bar, baz, foo, qux])

Comment: You can eliminate duplicates by converting to set and back to list `lst = list(set(df.index.droplevel(1)))`.

Comment: Alhamdulillah, many thanks to you mr @TimRoberts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
`df.index.unique(level=0)`
returns
Index(['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], dtype='object', name='first')